# What happens you delete a character in Animal Crossing New Leaf?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

When I'm going to play as a non-mayor character, Isabelle starts up my game and there are 2 options:

- Yes, lets
- I need help first...

When I pick "I need help first...", there are 4 options:

- Set the time
- Move to another town
- Demolish my home
- Re-create the town

When I choose "Demolish my home", Isabelle will ask if I'm really sure I want to delete 
that character. What happens when you delete a character?

Answer (score 2):

According to this [GameFAQs thread](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/997811-animal-crossing-new-leaf/67443561),

> If you demolish your home everything will be gone. Like the character
>   never existed so all things tied will disappear.

Comment: When I deleted a character in WIld World, the character's name in the museum was replaced with ???, but villagers could still refer to them by name, and show letters they'd received from the character.

Answer (score 0):

As MarioErmando already wrote, everything will be gone as if it has never existed. Only the character and house are deleted though, items that were dropped in your town by the to-be-deleted character will still be in your town.
This is only possible to do on a second character, since you can't create a second character and delete the first character aka the mayor.
If you want to delete the mayor of your town, you will need to recreate the town, which you can do so by using/clicking the "Re-create the town" option.

Answer (score -1):

After you confirm to Isabelle that you want to delete that character, that character will be removed from the game.